# Why is next() sometimes called implicitely on generator?

Tags: python, generator

I am just learning generators in Python. It seems that if you assign generator to a tuple then next() is called silently behind the scenes - as if unpacking was forcing that call. But if you assign to tuple with single value then you get generator object itself. Do I get it right?
Trivial code follows:

```
def generator(n):
    x = 0
    while x < n:
        yield x
        x = x + 1

(x,*foo) = generator(1)
print(x, foo)    
(x,*foo) = generator(3)
print(x, foo)
(x) = generator(1)
print(x)
```

Output is:

```
0 []
0 [1, 2]
<generator object generator at 0x05F06900>
```

Comment: can't recreate... `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on `*foo)`. Is this only for Py3?

Comment: @ClsForCookies ... yes that is a Python 3 expression

Comment: The second last line of code *assigns* a generator to a variable. The two earlier lines are unpacking and therefore *consuming* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines use [tuple packing/unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html): they yield all values from the generator and then set them to x and foo. This is because `(x, foo)` is syntax for a tuple (a pair of items).

However, `(x)` is syntax for a variable. You would get what you expected if you write `(x,)`, which is how tuples of size 1 are created.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax

```
(x) = generator(1)
```

is **not** a tuple of one item.  You want:

```
(x,) = generator(1)
```

or

```
x, = generator(1)
```

Then you'll find the generator is called, just as in your other examples, due to "unpacking".

Note that in the expression `(x, y)` it is not the `()` that make it a tuple, it is the comma.  The parentheses simply bound the expression `x, y`.